# Array List of Lists Python

Tags: python, csv, pickle, mnist

Hi I'm following a tutorial where they use the MNIST database. Now they use the cPickle to unzip the data and get a tuple of list and so on. I want to use my own data but I have it on csv format and I'm not sure how to convert to the MNIST format. I use 48 units for my training data and the last one is my desired result

Example of how I have the csv file:

```
1,2,3..........48,1
```

On the tutorial that I following they use this:

```
training_data, validation_data, test_data = cPickle.load(f)
```

And if I

print training_data

I get this:

```
(array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ..., 
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32), array([5, 0, 4, ..., 8, 4, 8]))
```

print training_data[0]

```
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
```

print training_data[0][0] Is a numpy.array() of the values of each set, and training_data[1][0] is and float32 with the desire output for every set.

And the code that I'm doing is like this, but Im confused about the array() and dtype=float32 showing on the prompt

```
def load(filename):
    finalDataset = []
    res = 0
    with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
        lines = csv.reader(csvfile)
        datos = list(lines)
        for i in datos:
            tempA = np.array(i[:len(datos)-2]).astype(np.float64)
            tempB = np.float64(i[len(datos)-1:])
            finalDataset.append((tempA,tempB))
    return finalDataset
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For understanding the data structure you can (initially) ignore the array() and dtype information. Basically you appear to need a two part tuple (lets call them LEFT and RIGHT). LEFT is a (rectangular) list of lists (i.e. a 2dimensional array) and RIGHT is a list (i.e. a 1dimensional array).

For each row in your csv you add the first n-1 entries as a new row to LEFT and the last entry to RIGHT.

With regards to your load function:
Your code creates each row as a separate 1dim array + value and then adds those as a tuple to a (python) list. This is not what you want. As described above you need a 2dim array holding the data and a 1dim array holding the expected results.

Extending a numpy array row by row is a bit tricky and should be avoided in most cases. You then have the choice of building up your data as a (python) list of list and then converting it en bloc into an numpy array, or, better, create a pre-sized empty numpy array and then fill it with your data.

The later concept I have used below:

```
def load(filename):
    # read file into a list of rows
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        lines = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
        rows = list(lines)

    # create empty numpy arrays of the required size
    data = np.empty((len(rows), len(rows[0])-1), dtype=np.float64)
    expected = np.empty((len(rows),), dtype=np.int64)

    # fill array with data from the csv-rows
    for i, row in enumerate(rows):
        data[i,:] = row[:-1]
        expected[i] = row[-1]

    training_data = data, expected
    return training_data
```

EDIT:
Note the really neat indexing features of both ordinary python lists and especially numpy arrays. Negative indices count from the end of the list, with -1 being the last entry -2 the second to last and so on.
`a:b` indexes a slice, i.e. entries with indices a, a+1, ... b-1. If `a` is left empty in that notation it means "from the first" and if `b` is left out it means "to the last" entry. Thus `:` means "everything". While ordinary python lists support this syntax in one dimension, numpy arrays extend this to multile dimensions by separating the indices for each dimension with colons.

EDIT2: The size of the empty numpy arrays was slightly off.

EDIT3: In response to your comment:

`type(training_data) = <type 'tuple'>` means that `training_data` is a tuple (with two elements).

`type(training_data[0]) = <type 'numpy.ndarray'>` means that `training_data[0]` is a numpy array (for simplified understanding consider this to be equivalent to a list).

`type(training_data[1]) = <type 'numpy.ndarray'>` means that `training_data[1]` is also a numpy array/list.

`type(training_data[0][0]) = <type 'numpy.ndarray'>` shows that each element of `training_data[0]` is itself an array/list.

`type(training_data[1][0]) = <type 'numpy.int64'>` shows that each element of `training_data[1]` is a single value.

With `len(training_data[0])` and `len(training_data[1])` you can see that for each entry in `training_data[0]` (=this is a list of values, i.e. your input-data) there is a corresponding entry in `training_data[1]` (this is a single value, i.e. your expected result value).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm not sure if I let the correct idea, but I need the two lists together, data and expected. I mean for example :

first row contents all, data and result, so I need a array with tuple, and the tuples has a array list and the float number. Or that's what I think. In this case with your code I slices into datas and responses, and I need the responses of each row at the side

Comment: And I can't tell exactly how is the estructure that I want because I don-t understand it very well. This are the results of thea types of each elment on the structure: type(training_data) = <type 'tuple'>, type(training_data[0]) = <type 'numpy.ndarray'>, type(training_data[1]) = <type 'numpy.ndarray'>, type(training_data[0][0]) = <type 'numpy.ndarray'> and type(training_data[1][0]) = <type 'numpy.int64'>.

Comment: Do you whish to convert from csv to the structure of training_data or the other way around?

Comment: Yes, I want to convert from csv to the training_data structture.

Comment: Then you should be able to use the function above as is. (There were still some minor bugs, sorry about that. But now the code is tested and valid.)

Comment: Thanks, yes it has some bugs but now I understand in a better form how to do it.